# Does a dialup connection usually give you an IP address?

Tags: ip-address, dial-up

I am trying to test remote connections to my LAN.  If I use a dialup connection will I get an IP address I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will usually get a public, dynamically assigned, ip address that you can connect to from the 'net. Use something like the good old [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) to find yourself from outside.

Some providers could assign you a non-internet-routable RFC1918 address, they'll do NAT for you in that case to let you surf the 'net but you won't be able to connect from the outside in that case. See [Private Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). If that's the case, you need to initiate the connection from the inside to a known, reachable, outside address (ie, do things the other way round).
There are 'hosted vpn' services out there (you connect both your home and your laptop to the (known, public) vpn server and the two will be able to communicate).

Comment: +1 Agreed with Luke404, sometimes you get a public IP address, sometimes your ISP use NAT to give you external access.

Answer (score 0):

In general yes, unless your ISP gives you a private address (like 192.168.x.y).

I regularly use SSH to connect to my home network.

Comment: How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ipchicken.com/

will tell you what your current web facing ip address is, but if you have been given a private address (like 192.168.x.y) then you will probably not be able to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to run the services on the machine that is connected directly to the internet, then Yes, in most cases you can.

Obviously trying to serve anything via a dial-up connection is going to be horribly slow and if the internet connection is being used by anyone else then it is likely to be virtually unusable.

Hope that helps.